# What is meaning of this Scheduler expression -> *~*~*~*~*/6~0~0?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, ejb-timer

What is meaning of this Scheduler expression. Not sure is it a Quartz Expression or timer service of ejb but i am sure the projects are using among this.

[image]

```
*~*~*~*~*/6~0~0
*~*~*~*~5~15~0
```

So not able to understand especially the one */6

Could anyone please elaborate on same?

Comment: I am not sure where these expressions come from, but I can assure you these are not valid Quartz cron expressions. When I try to use them, I am getting "java.text.ParseException: Unexpected end of expression." from Quartz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/ used to specify repetitive schedules,

For Example 2/3 in minutes range specifies,

> Every 3 minutes, starting at 2 minutes past the hour

Quartz scheduler dose not support */6, in quartz */6 is equivalent to 0/6

/ - used to specify increments. For example, “0/15” in the seconds field means “the seconds 0, 15, 30, and 45”. And “5/15” in the seconds field means “the seconds 5, 20, 35, and 50”. You can also specify ‘/’ after the ‘’ character - in this case ‘’ is equivalent to having ‘0’ before the ‘/’. ‘1/3’ in the day-of-month field means “fire every 3 days starting on the first day of the month”.

from: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html